# How can i convert this string to system.datetime in C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Here is my date javascript string .I am passing this string from ajax and want to catch and convert in `system.Datetime`

**Wed Dec 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

```
    DateTime dateSelected;

    dateSelected = Convert.ToDateTime("my string");
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you in control of the string you're passing? It's almost certainly going to be simpler to change the Javascript to pass in a more sensible machine-readable format such as ISO-8601.

Comment: You mean to pass the string in different format.@Jon Skeet

Comment: @jsatapathy, what is your string format? Is it "MM/dd/yyyy" or anything else?

Comment: Yes, exactly - ideally something like `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` as per ISO-8601.

Comment: @Golda: See the example before the code. It's a not-terribly-nice format for machine parsing...

Comment: so 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' string format can be converted.right?@Jon Skeet

Comment: @jsatapathy, have you tried TryParseExact method? DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
     DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime). In format you can mention the date format which in string

Comment: pass more sensible format, or write a parser for this output

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx

Answer (score -1):

you can make use of moment.js library for having nicely formatted dates in java script

and then pass that formatted string through ajax to c# code.

Answer (score -1):

use this, 
time1 is the label

time1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");